# Thevenin-Norton Conversion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

Using Thévenin-Norton equivalence, prove that the circuit below

[image]

is equivalent to the circuit below

[image]

---

The main point behind my confusion is that the current source has no parallel resistance. As a result, I am unable to apply the Thévenin-Norton equivalence to it. Can anyone give me a hint about what to do with the current source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different things with similar names.

1) The Thevenin-Norton equivalence. Or the Thevenin-Norton transformation.

You can convert a Thevenin input into a Norton input, and vice-versa.

That means, [a voltage source in series with a resistance] is, as a block, equivalent to a [current source in parallel with anojther resistance].

You can convert from one to another very easily.

But there is also a different thing:

2) The Thevenin equivalent of a given circuit.

For a linear circuit, you can always reduce it to a Thevenin circuit.

That means, you can have a ver complicated circuit, with many resistors, capacitors, sources, and so on.

Provided that it is linear, it can always be reduced to a [Voltage source + resistance in series].

In other words, if you replace the whole circuit with this Thevening one, nobody will note. The result is the same "as seen from" the terminals.

### So, how to do it?

You'll find many other better explanations, but, in short, it is:

A) For the voltage source:  measure the voltage in open circuit

B) For the resistance: void all independent generators (not depednent ones!, only independent) And, after that, calculate teh equivalent resistance seen from the terminals.

When I say "measure", it can also be "calculate it".

Hope this helps